# How can I display a message on an option pane?

Tags: java, user-interface, joptionpane

I am creating a program which allows you to display a message on an option pane after clicking a button.

```
String ManID;
String ManName;
ManID = ManIDText.getText();
ManName = ManNameText.getText();


try
{
    File f=new File("Manager.txt");
    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(f,true))) {
        pw.append(ManID + "," + ManName + "\r\n");
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddCust.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        // TODO add your handling code here:
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Manager Added");
    }
```

is there any problems with the coding?

Comment: Maybe? But only you will know this, right? Does the code compile? Does it meet the requirements? Put another way, what is your question?

Comment: well yes it does seem to meet the requirements and it is able to compile. What I want to know is how to get the JOption Panel to change message depending on the situation, such as if the Manager name is already in the system and cannot be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

There are several, overloaded `showMessageDialog` methods in class `JOptionPane`. According to the code you posted, you are supplying two parameters. The first is a `java.awt.Component` - which may be null, by the way - and the second is `java.lang.Object`. In other words, the second parameter can be anything you like. In the code you posted, it is `java.lang.String`. In fact it is a string literal. You can just as well use a variable of type `String` as in...

```
String var = "I am a 'String' variable";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, var);
```

Of-course you don't need to assign a string literal to the variable, you can assign it any value you want that you obtained any way you want, for example the value returned by a method, as in...

```
String var = getSomeString();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, var);
```

Remember, it doesn't have to be a `String`. It can be a scrollable `JTextArea`, for example.